# MongoDB 2.6 + NodeJS can't iterate cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I really can't figure out what's wrong, please help.

MongoDB version 2.6.7

I can insert without any problem, however **Find** function preforms very wired, see below codes.

**Code A works very well.**

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 

mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/feeding", function(err,database){
    if(!err){
        db.collection('test').find({}).toArray(function(err, users){
            console.log(users);
        });
        app.listen(8888, function(){
            console.log("Server Started");
        });
    }else{
        console.dir(err);
    }
});
```

**Below B code** throws `'TypeError: undefined is not a function' at line 25`

```
var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 

mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/feeding", function(err,database){
    if(!err){
        var cursor = db.collection('test').find({});
        while (cursor.hasNext()) { //line 25
            console.log("printed");
        }
        app.listen(8888, function(){
            console.log("Server Started");
        });
    }else{
        console.dir(err);
    }
});
```

I believe it says hasNext() is not a function, but refer to MongoDB document http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/, seems the code doesn't have any problem, have spent few hours on the issue. anybody can give me a suggestion?

Comment: This is a shell command, not for the mongodb driver

Comment: Check http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html

Comment: @ZeMoon thanks, didn't realized that.

Comment: Great, have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines from code B are supposed to be used in a Mongo shell, and not in the Node.js script. For that, you will need to use the Node.js MongoDB driver.

Check the docs for the cursor object [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html).

You will need to use the `cursor.nextObject()` method and check whether the object returned is `null`, which will indicate that you have reached the end.